# Fastest way to find minimum value in each column

Tags: algorithm, matrix, time-complexity, complexity-theory, minimum

I have `log n` rows, and each row containing `n` numbers.

I want the find the minimum value at each position among all the rows:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[3, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 1, 2]
[9, 7, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1]
```

should result in a array looking like this:

```
[1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

I would be easy to make a brute force method in `O(nlogn)` time

I can even see a divide and conquer solution which would split the rows in half and run the algorithm recursively on each side, that would take `O(nloglogn)` time.

But I can't see a way to remove the `n`. The way I see it, I need to look at each position in at least one of the rows at least once.

Is there a way to make the complexity smaller?

Comment: Is there any relation between the numbers in the matrix?

Comment: Can you tell your approach for O(n loglog n) solution?

Comment: There are distances between nodes in a graph, which means there is a upper bound on the numbers, other then that, no.

Comment: For an array having random values, you can't find min value without traversing the whole array once, atleast (as next element can always be lesser than current min). I don't think there is a solution other than accessing all elements.

Comment: I don't think there's a quicker solution than the trivial O(n * n)

Comment: If the array runs recursively on both sides after you split the array, the complexity will be O(n). [n in your case is log n obvs.].Binary search is O(log n) as we discard half of array in each turn.

Comment: Why not write it as `n*m`?

Comment: If it runs on each side with log(n)/2 rows and still n number of columns, and then continue splitting, wouldn't it be log(log(n)) in height times n in breadth then?

Comment: @F.Ju just wanted to point out the special relationship between the two. If it would help.

Comment: @Krycke The time complexity is `O(nlogn loglog n)` not `O(nloglogn)`

Comment: Dividing a problem in half and then running an algorithm for each half doesn't give you a log. If you were able to eliminate one of the halves, you would have a case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an array of size X is not sorted or structured in some known special way, then cost for finding element `y` in it must be equal to X, because you cant skip any element in X (the skipped one can be the solution).

The order of searching does not matter either. If you split it and divide and conquer etc., still the element `y` can be the last one you visit.

Therefore if you have an array of size `n*logn`, the lowest possible complexity is `Omega(n* log n)`.